# Cannot use .replaceWith() function to remove all html code between tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does `.replaceWith()` not work in the following code?

After clicking the radio button, the HTML between the `<form>` is removed.

```
$('input:radio').click( function(){                        
   var url = $(this).attr('alt');                       
   $('form').replaceWith($('<form action="'+url+'" method="post" class="url">' + this.innerHTML + '</form>'));                        
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/MWFN9/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is change the value of the `action` attribute when a radio button is clicked.

`replaceWith` replaces the entire element (and it's children) which is why your entire form is replaced (with an empty one).

Instead, you can use `attr` to change the value of a single attribute:

```
$('input:radio').click(function() {                        
    var url = $(this).attr('alt');                       
    $('form').attr("action", url);                        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A `input[type=radio]` does not have any `innerHTML`. The ***form*** does, on the other hand.

I think however, you want some code like this instead:

```
$('input:radio').click( function(){                        
    var url = $(this).attr('alt');                       

    $(this).closest('form').attr('action', url); // Target the form for this input, rather than the first form in the document ($('form')).
});
```

See a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MWFN9/2/, and check out the documentation for the [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) method.

Answer (score 0):

`this` in the second line of your handler refers to `input` element. Therefore `this.innerHTML` is empty. You get the form recreated with no contents.